# Sparkasse S-pushTAN app keeps crashing after restored with Titanium Backup

Tags: restore, crashes, titanium-backup

I'm a long time user of Titanium backup but recently I discovered that when I try to restore an app about 50% of the apps are not getting correctly recovered. After the restore the app always force closes.
Now I want ti investigate this further.
So I restored an App (com.starfinanz.mobile.android.pushtan) using Titanium Backup but the App always FCs now.
Device LG-G6 (h870) Havoc OS (Android 10)

I already tried restorecon -R -v /data/data but with no success

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong?
When I clear the data of the app it starts working again (but ofcourse I need to setup all the settings again ...)

This is the logcat when I try to start the app

```
01-29 10:01:37.453   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Ctx: poll:polldata:1, sensor:1, type:1, x:0.682343 y:7.575256 z:5.834671
01-29 10:01:37.454   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Util: waitForResponse: timeout=0
01-29 10:01:37.493   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Ctx: poll:polldata:1, sensor:1, type:1, x:0.699112 y:7.580048 z:5.789185
01-29 10:01:37.493   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Util: waitForResponse: timeout=0
01-29 10:01:37.533   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Ctx: poll:polldata:1, sensor:1, type:1, x:0.684738 y:7.565674 z:5.839462
01-29 10:01:37.533   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Util: waitForResponse: timeout=0
01-29 10:01:37.574   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Ctx: poll:polldata:1, sensor:1, type:1, x:0.677567 y:7.601593 z:5.825089
01-29 10:01:37.574   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Util: waitForResponse: timeout=0
01-29 10:01:37.613   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Ctx: poll:polldata:1, sensor:1, type:1, x:0.677567 y:7.580048 z:5.817917
01-29 10:01:37.613   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Util: waitForResponse: timeout=0
01-29 10:01:37.654   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Ctx: poll:polldata:1, sensor:1, type:1, x:0.665588 y:7.582443 z:5.822693
01-29 10:01:37.654   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Util: waitForResponse: timeout=0
01-29 10:01:37.694   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Ctx: poll:polldata:1, sensor:1, type:1, x:0.679947 y:7.568069 z:5.822693
01-29 10:01:37.695   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Util: waitForResponse: timeout=0
01-29 10:01:37.735   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Ctx: poll:polldata:1, sensor:1, type:1, x:0.653610 y:7.563278 z:5.796356
01-29 10:01:37.735   604  1024 D sensors_hal_Util: waitForResponse: timeout=0
01-29 10:01:39.467  1006  9682 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.starfinanz.mobile.android.pushtan/com.starfinanz.mobile.android.spushtan.SPushTan bnds=[346,800][618,1100]} from uid 10241
01-29 10:01:39.512  1006  1134 E system_server: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
01-29 10:01:39.553   536   536 D Zygote  : Forked child process 6134
01-29 10:01:39.563  1006  1156 I ActivityManager: Start proc 6134:com.starfinanz.mobile.android.pushtan/u0a323 for pre-top-activity {com.starfinanz.mobile.android.pushtan/com.starfinanz.mobile.android.spushtan.SPushTan}
01-29 10:01:39.565  6134  6134 E android.pushta: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
01-29 10:01:39.573   520   526 I Magisk  : proc_monitor: [com.starfinanz.mobile.android.pushtan] PID=[6134] UID=[10323]
01-29 10:01:39.586  1006  4735 W OomAdjuster: Fallback pre-set sched group to default: not expected top priority
01-29 10:01:39.700  2842 27860 W NetworkScheduler: Error inserting flex_time=694000 job_id=-1 period=1390000 source=16 requires_charging=0 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService user_id=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG task_type=0 required_idleness_state=0 service_kind=0 source_version=205016000 persistence_level=1 preferred_charging_state=1 required_network_type=0 runtime=1611910899693 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0, error message: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE) [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
01-29 10:01:39.903  6134  6134 W ndroid.settings: type=1400 audit(0.0:1687835): avc: denied { read } for name="tcp" dev="proc" ino=4026532383 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c67,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_net_tcp_udp:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-29 10:01:39.906  6134  6134 W ndroid.settings: type=1400 audit(0.0:1687836): avc: denied { read } for name="enforce" dev="selinuxfs" ino=4 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c67,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:selinuxfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-29 10:01:39.930  6134  6134 W ndroid.settings: type=1400 audit(0.0:1687837): avc: denied { read } for name="tcp" dev="proc" ino=4026532383 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c67,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_net_tcp_udp:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-29 10:01:39.983  2166  2166 D ImageWallpaper: wallpaper visibility changes to: false
01-29 10:01:40.004  6134  6134 I FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
01-29 10:01:40.006  6134  6134 W         : type=1400 audit(0.0:1687838): avc: denied { read } for name="tcp" dev="proc" ino=4026532383 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c67,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_net_tcp_udp:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-29 10:01:40.023  6134  6134 W         : type=1400 audit(0.0:1687839): avc: denied { read } for name="tcp" dev="proc" ino=4026532383 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c67,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_net_tcp_udp:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-29 10:01:40.080  6134  6134 I FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
01-29 10:01:40.303  6134  6175 W LOTTIE  : Lottie doesn't support expressions.
01-29 10:01:40.496  6134  6134 I [Koin]  : loaded 79 definitions - 215.285543 ms
01-29 10:01:40.585  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 7f found for ID 0x7f010000.
01-29 10:01:40.585  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 7f found for ID 0x7f020000.
01-29 10:01:40.585  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 7f found for ID 0x7f030000.
01-29 10:01:40.585  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 7f found for ID 0x7f040000.
01-29 10:01:40.585  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 7f found for ID 0x7f050000.
01-29 10:01:40.585  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 7f found for ID 0x7f060000.
01-29 10:01:40.585  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 7f found for ID 0x7f070000.
01-29 10:01:40.585  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 7f found for ID 0x7f080000.
01-29 10:01:40.585  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 7f found for ID 0x7f090000.
01-29 10:01:40.585  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 7f found for ID 0x7f0a0000.
01-29 10:01:40.585  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 7f found for ID 0x7f0b0000.
01-29 10:01:40.585  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 7f found for ID 0x7f0c0000.
01-29 10:01:40.585  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 7f found for ID 0x7f0d0000.
01-29 10:01:40.586  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 80 found for ID 0x80010000.
01-29 10:01:40.586  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 80 found for ID 0x80010001.
01-29 10:01:40.723  6134  6174 W LOTTIE  : Lottie doesn't support layer effects. If you are using them for  fills, strokes, trim paths etc. then try adding them directly as contents  in your shape. Found: [Excite - Transformieren - Skal]
01-29 10:01:40.790  6134  6160 W android.pushta: resources.arsc in APK '/data/app/com.instagram.android-lIIPSoO2Fu30Wa4t86NTUQ==/base.apk' is compressed.
01-29 10:01:40.868  6134  6160 W android.pushta: resources.arsc in APK '/data/app/com.maxmpz.audioplayer-JCugQCvMXfGvHpOsecZdYA==/base.apk' is compressed.
01-29 10:01:40.904  6134  6160 W android.pushta: resources.arsc in APK '/data/app/com.maxmpz.audioplayer.unlock-g191wh8faIPG7UkV3iZDtw==/base.apk' is compressed.
01-29 10:01:40.981  6134  6174 W LOTTIE  : Animation contains merge paths. Merge paths are only supported on KitKat+ and must be manually enabled by calling enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove().
01-29 10:01:41.000  6134  6134 W         : type=1400 audit(0.0:1687840): avc: denied { read } for name="tcp" dev="proc" ino=4026532383 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c67,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_net_tcp_udp:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-29 10:01:41.174  6134  6180 I AdrenoGLES: QUALCOMM build                   : 7331a27, Ieeb4a86f7b
01-29 10:01:41.174  6134  6180 I AdrenoGLES: Build Date                       : 11/13/19
01-29 10:01:41.174  6134  6180 I AdrenoGLES: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.27.05.02
01-29 10:01:41.174  6134  6180 I AdrenoGLES: Local Branch                     : 
01-29 10:01:41.174  6134  6180 I AdrenoGLES: Remote Branch                    : 
01-29 10:01:41.174  6134  6180 I AdrenoGLES: Remote Branch                    : 
01-29 10:01:41.174  6134  6180 I AdrenoGLES: Reconstruct Branch               : 
01-29 10:01:41.174  6134  6180 I AdrenoGLES: Build Config                     : S L 8.0.12 AArch64
01-29 10:01:41.182  6134  6180 I AdrenoGLES: PFP: 0x005ff087, ME: 0x005ff063
01-29 10:01:41.219   465   465 I hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry android.hardware.graphics.mapper@3.0::IMapper/default in either framework or device manifest.
01-29 10:01:41.220  6134  6180 W Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
01-29 10:01:41.222   465  6185 W libc    : Unable to set property "ctl.interface_start" to "android.hardware.graphics.mapper@3.0::IMapper/default": error code: 0x20
01-29 10:01:41.222   465  6185 E hwservicemanager: Failed to set property for starting android.hardware.graphics.mapper@3.0::IMapper/default
01-29 10:01:41.277  1006  1149 I ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.starfinanz.mobile.android.pushtan/com.starfinanz.mobile.android.spushtan.SPushTan: +1s786ms
01-29 10:01:41.338  6134  6134 W android.pushta: Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getOrCreateResources(Landroid/os/IBinder;Landroid/content/res/ResourcesKey;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Landroid/content/res/Resources; (greylist-max-o, reflection, denied)
01-29 10:01:41.336  6134  6134 W ndroid.settings: type=1400 audit(0.0:1687841): avc: denied { read } for name="tcp" dev="proc" ino=4026532383 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c67,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_net_tcp_udp:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-29 10:01:41.340  6134  6134 W ndroid.settings: type=1400 audit(0.0:1687842): avc: denied { read } for name="enforce" dev="selinuxfs" ino=4 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c67,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:selinuxfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-29 10:01:41.343  6134  6176 W LOTTIE  : Lottie doesn't support layer effects. If you are using them for  fills, strokes, trim paths etc. then try adding them directly as contents  in your shape. Found: [IK]
01-29 10:01:41.434  6134  6134 I TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
01-29 10:01:41.493  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 80 found for ID 0x80010000.
01-29 10:01:41.493  6134  6160 E android.pushta: No package ID 80 found for ID 0x80010001.
01-29 10:01:41.509  2842 27860 I NetworkScheduler.Stats: Task com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.clearcut.uploader.QosUploaderService started execution. cause:1 exec_start_elapsed_seconds: 90226 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
01-29 10:01:41.583  2842 32121 I NetworkScheduler.Stats: Task com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.gcmtask.TapAndPayGcmTaskService started execution. cause:1 exec_start_elapsed_seconds: 90226 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
01-29 10:01:41.606  2842 30294 I NetworkScheduler.Stats: Task com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.gcmtask.TapAndPayGcmTaskService finished executing. cause:1 result: 1 elapsed_millis: 71 uptime_millis: 71 exec_start_elapsed_seconds: 90226 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
01-29 10:01:41.626  1006 13990 D BiometricService: canAuthenticate: User=0, Caller=0
01-29 10:01:41.626  1006 13990 D BiometricService: checkAndGetBiometricModality: user=0 isHardwareDetected=true hasTemplatesEnrolled=true enabledForApps=true
01-29 10:01:41.642   789   789 I keystore: del USRPKEY_KEY_STORE_TEST_KEY 10323
01-29 10:01:41.643   789   789 I keystore: del USRSKEY_KEY_STORE_TEST_KEY 10323
01-29 10:01:41.643   789   789 I keystore: del USRCERT_KEY_STORE_TEST_KEY 10323
01-29 10:01:41.644   789   789 I keystore: del CACERT_KEY_STORE_TEST_KEY 10323
01-29 10:01:41.647   500   500 W /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-service: Not performing software digesting for symmetric cipher keys
01-29 10:01:41.647   500   500 W /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-service: Not performing software digesting for symmetric cipher keys
01-29 10:01:41.659   679   691 D DrmLibTime: got the req here! ret=0
01-29 10:01:41.659   679   691 D DrmLibTime: command id, time_cmd_id = 770
01-29 10:01:41.659   679   691 D DrmLibTime: time_getutcsec starts!
01-29 10:01:41.659   679   691 D DrmLibTime: QSEE Time Listener: time_getutcsec
01-29 10:01:41.659   679   691 D DrmLibTime: QSEE Time Listener: get_utc_seconds
01-29 10:01:41.659   679   691 D DrmLibTime: QSEE Time Listener: time_get_modem_time
01-29 10:01:41.659   679   691 D DrmLibTime: QSEE Time Listener: Checking if ATS_MODEM is set or not.
01-29 10:01:41.659   679   691 D QC-time-services: Lib:time_genoff_operation: pargs->base = 13
01-29 10:01:41.659   679   691 D QC-time-services: Lib:time_genoff_operation: pargs->operation = 2
01-29 10:01:41.659   679   691 D QC-time-services: Lib:time_genoff_operation: pargs->ts_val = 0
01-29 10:01:41.660   679   691 D QC-time-services: Lib:time_genoff_operation: Send to server  passed!!
01-29 10:01:41.660   731   766 D QC-time-services: Daemon: Connection accepted:time_genoff
01-29 10:01:41.661   731  6190 D QC-time-services: Daemon:Received base = 13, unit = 1, operation = 2,value = 0
01-29 10:01:41.661   731  6190 D QC-time-services: Daemon:genoff_opr: Base = 13, val = 0, operation = 2
01-29 10:01:41.661   731  6190 D QC-time-services: offset is: 0 for base: 13
01-29 10:01:41.661   679   691 E QC-time-services: Receive Passed == base = 13, unit = 1, operation = 2, result = 0
01-29 10:01:41.661   679   691 D DrmLibTime: QSEE Time Listener: ATS_MODEM is not set. Fallback to Android system time.
01-29 10:01:41.661   679   691 D DrmLibTime: QSEE Time Listener: Retrieved Android system time: 1611910901
01-29 10:01:41.661   679   691 D DrmLibTime: time_getutcsec returns 0, sec = 1611910901; nsec = 0
01-29 10:01:41.661   679   691 D DrmLibTime: time_getutcsec finished! 
01-29 10:01:41.661   679   691 D DrmLibTime: iotcl_continue_command finished! and return 0 
01-29 10:01:41.661   679   691 D DrmLibTime: before calling ioctl to read the next time_cmd
01-29 10:01:41.662   731   766 E QC-time-services: Daemon: Time-services: Waiting to acceptconnection
01-29 10:01:41.671   789  6189 W /system/bin/keystore: Trying to serialize unknown tag 1879048895. Did you forget to add it to all_tags_t?
01-29 10:01:41.683   789  6189 D DropBoxManager: About to call service->add()
01-29 10:01:41.684  1006 13990 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=keymaster isTagEnabled=true flags=0x0
01-29 10:01:41.698   789  6189 D DropBoxManager: service->add returned No error
01-29 10:01:41.708   789   789 I keystore: del USRPKEY_KEY_STORE_TEST_KEY 10323
01-29 10:01:41.709   789   789 I keystore: del USRCERT_KEY_STORE_TEST_KEY 10323
01-29 10:01:41.710   789   789 I keystore: del CACERT_KEY_STORE_TEST_KEY 10323
01-29 10:01:41.733   500   500 W /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-service: Not performing software digesting for symmetric cipher keys
01-29 10:01:41.733   500   500 W /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-service: Not performing software digesting for symmetric cipher keys
01-29 10:01:41.744   500   500 E keymaster1_device: Finish send cmd failed
01-29 10:01:41.744   500   500 E keymaster1_device: ret: 0
01-29 10:01:41.744   500   500 E keymaster1_device: resp->status: -38
01-29 10:01:41.746  6134  6134 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.starfinanz.mobile.android.pushtan, PID: 6134
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:501)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 1 more
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:515)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at sf.bu1.a(SourceFile:14)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at sf.sj1.b(SourceFile:7)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at sf.oj1.l(SourceFile:1)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at sf.bp1.j(SourceFile:2)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at sf.nl1.r(SourceFile:2)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.starfinanz.mobile.android.pushtan.presentation.login.LoginFragment.h0(SourceFile:2)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at sf.uc.V(SourceFile:178)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at sf.uc.T(SourceFile:4)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at sf.uc.U(SourceFile:6)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at sf.uc.E(SourceFile:81)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at sf.uc.a0(SourceFile:11)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at sf.uc.C(SourceFile:14)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at sf.uc$d.run(SourceFile:1)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 3 more
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid argument
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1303)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:224)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:506)
01-29 10:01:41.747  6134  6134 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 21 more
01-29 10:01:41.753  1006  8684 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.starfinanz.mobile.android.pushtan/com.starfinanz.mobile.android.spushtan.SPushTan
01-29 10:01:41.754  1006  6198 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
01-29 10:01:41.762  1006  7410 E BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-1006-69] setMaxDequeuedBufferCount: 2 dequeued buffers would exceed the maxBufferCount (2) (maxAcquired 1 async 0 mDequeuedBufferCannotBlock 0)
01-29 10:01:41.764  1006  7410 E Surface : IGraphicBufferProducer::setBufferCount(3) returned Invalid argument
01-29 10:01:41.767  2842 27860 W NetworkScheduler: Error inserting flex_time=692000 job_id=-1 period=1386000 source=16 requires_charging=0 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService user_id=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG task_type=0 required_idleness_state=0 service_kind=0 source_version=205016000 persistence_level=1 preferred_charging_state=1 required_network_type=0 runtime=1611910901719 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0, error message: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE) [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
01-29 10:01:41.781  2842 30294 I NetworkScheduler.Stats: Task com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.checkin.EventLogService started execution. cause:5 exec_start_elapsed_seconds: 90226 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
01-29 10:01:41.783  6134  6134 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 6134 SIG: 9
01-29 10:01:41.785   670   670 E lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/6134/oom_score_adj; errno=22
01-29 10:01:41.817  3196 32486 I Checkin : [EventLogChimeraService] Opted in for usage reporting: false
01-29 10:01:41.817  3196 32486 I Checkin : [EventLogChimeraService] Aggregate from 1611908802786 (log), 1611908802786 (data)
01-29 10:01:41.853  1006 13990 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{437b4c7 u0 com.starfinanz.mobile.android.pushtan/com.starfinanz.mobile.android.spushtan.SPushTan}
01-29 10:01:41.855  1006  2664 I ActivityManager: Process com.starfinanz.mobile.android.pushtan (pid 6134) has died: vis+99 TOP 
01-29 10:01:41.879  1006  1133 W ActivityManager: setHasOverlayUi called on unknown pid: 6134
01-29 10:01:41.904  2166  2181 I ndroid.systemu: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 228514(9951KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(1408KB) LOS objects, 53% free, 10MB/22MB, paused 101us total 122.266ms
01-29 10:01:41.908  2166  2166 D ImageWallpaper: wallpaper visibility changes to: true
01-29 10:01:41.927   536   536 I Zygote  : Process 6134 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)
01-29 10:01:41.946  1006  1157 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10323 pid 6134 in 89ms
01-29 10:01:42.144  1006  4312 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=event_log isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
01-29 10:01:42.159  1006  4312 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=event_data isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
01-29 10:01:42.226  2842 32121 I NetworkScheduler.Stats: Task com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.checkin.EventLogService finished executing. cause:5 result: 1 elapsed_millis: 505 uptime_millis: 505 exec_start_elapsed_seconds: 90226 [CONTEXT service_id=218 ]
01-29 10:01:42.254  1006  1133 W ActivityTaskManager: Activity top resumed state loss timeout for ActivityRecord{d9661ce u0 com.starfinanz.mobile.android.pushtan/com.starfinanz.mobile.android.spushtan.SPushTan t-1 f}
01-29 10:01:42.374  2842  2270 W Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
01-29 10:01:42.404  2842  2270 W Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@205016037@20.50.16 (120400-351607135):2)
01-29 10:01:42.404  2842  2270 W Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@205016037@20.50.16 (120400-351607135):0)
01-29 10:01:42.456  2842  2270 W Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
01-29 10:01:42.457  2842  2270 W Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@205016037@20.50.16 (120400-351607135):2)
01-29 10:01:42.457  2842  2270 W Conscrypt:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@205016037@20.50.16 (120400-351607135):0)
```

Comment: The StarFinance programs and apps are usually heavily obfuscated and protected against cloning and manipulation. I would assume that all data this app creates is bound to your device. Therefore this app implements anti-backup/cloning measurements. Ask the app developer company and they will most likely tell you something similar.

Comment: I already orderer a new activation code so thats not that big of a deal this time. But this backup is from the same device running the same OS (its really exactly the same device without any SO update in between) So I think it should be possible to recover the state. When I ask the company they will tell me "You are not allowed to use this app on a rooted device" So I don't think that I get any useful information from them.

Comment: I would assume that this app uses the hardware based AndroidKeystore which Titanium can not backup. There are other apps that also use AndroidKeystore and thus can't be backuped by Titanium. See for example here: [TWRP Backup restoring Line/Whatsapp problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203585/2241)